# How to use two AS operators in one column?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to select ONLY date part from my datetime column. I says:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
FROM Intensity
```

And its work fine. But wne i use this query in JDBC:

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] FROM Intensity";
ResultSet r=sta.executeQuery(sql);
String json="";
json=json+"{'data':[";
while(r.next()){
    json=json+"'"+r.getDate("Date")+"',";
}
```

I get error that: The column name Date is not valid.
Its possible to rename column when i already use `AS` operator or rewrite this query in more optimal form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a java programmer, but I suspect you want this:

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS MyDate FROM Intensity";
ResultSet r=sta.executeQuery(sql);
String json="";
json=json+"{'data':[";
while(r.next()){
    json=json+"'"+r.getString("MyDate")+"',";
}
```

Comment: Last approach will retrieve `MyDate` with no problems, but it won't fulfill nor the JSON format in case of data change and the format of the `Date` won't be the desired one.

Comment: The AS clause doesn't format the date.  It renames the field.  The 103 specifier on the convert is what tells it what format to put the date in.  103 means to put it into dd/mm/yyyy format as the british/french like it.

Comment: I know, but since you're not a Java programmer, you probably don't understand that `Date#toString()` will be called when concatenating the `Date` object with the `String` and `Date#toString` has a default (and probably not desired) format.

Comment: Ah, and it isn't really a date at that point either since it has already been converted to a string on the server.  So he probably should be calling r.getString("MyDate") or similiar function.

Comment: OP should use a `SimpleDateFormat` to handle this. But as you said, you're not a Java programmer so is not your fault to not knowing this :).

Comment: Editted answer with change from getDate to getString

Comment: Yeah. I thought that `[DD/MM/YYYY]` needs form date format, and make error with `r.getDate()`. Thanks you form help.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: SimpleDateFormat would work against the DISTINCT.  Easier to CONVERT in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving it a try. It may be because of the slash(/). Try to convert the sql as:

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS [DD\/MM\/YYYY] FROM Intensity";
```

or

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS [DD//MM//YYYY] FROM Intensity";
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert McKee and Luiggi Mendoze have correct answer via comments (have voted them up):

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intensity.Date, 103) AS MyDate FROM Intensity";
ResultSet r=sta.executeQuery(sql);
String json="";
json=json+"{'data':[";
while(r.next()){
    json=json+"'"+r.getString("MyDate")+"',";
}
```